# How to check in Firebird if a datarow can be deleted?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, firebird, delete-row

I have a Firebird database with a table A, including ID primary key.
And several other tables like: table B, including A_ID foreign key to A.ID (on delete NO ACTION).

Now I want to check in a stored procedure if a row in A can be deleted.
Not actually delete it, only if it would be possible without errors.

But I don't want to check every other table that has a foreign key to A.

What I need is something like:

1. ```
   safepoint X;  
   delete from A where ID = 1;  
   when any do  
   begin  
     return = 'false';  
   end  
   rollback to X;
   ```

   But savepoints are not allowed in stored procedures.

Or

2. a way to check for an A.ID if there are rows in other tables referencing it.
   Without selecting every other table manually.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There's immediate problem with this. Once you return the result other transaction might modify the database and the result will not be correct.

Comment: The creation of rows that references A.ID is only user triggered.
And in my case, i can assume that when i check that this A can be deleted than it would be also deletable a minute later.
But yes, your point in true. When i actually delete it i have to check for the foreign keys again.
But in my case it is very unprobable that there are new references after i checked that A. I want this check only to have a message for the user that there are references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the [autonomous transactions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-inauton) introduced in Firebird 2.5 to do the check, and simply rollback afterwards. However this will probably introduce a deadlock problem because the row will be 'modified' by a different transaction than the parent transaction.

Ask yourself: why bother. Just try to delete and give the user a message if deletion wasn't possible.

Comment: My problem is:  
1. User is pressing a button and only when A can be deleted it should start a chain of events. Otherwise it should show a message.
2. At the end of the events a other program than the user is using should delete A.
That program can log the delete errors. But the user will not see it. And this chain should only be started when a can be deleted.

Comment: Then I guess there is no other option to discover all foreign key references and check them

Comment: Thx, with the autonomous transactions it works.
Thx also to cincura.net (sorry Mark was faster ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

As Mark said you can run it in [`IN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-inauton). It's automatically committed, but you can throw exception there as a last command and in that case it's rolled back.

But for your case I would first try to just delete and rollback (in any case). If you get error, it cannot be completed. Otherwise you can continue with other actions you described. This will be cheaper than fiddling with stored procedure and `autonomous transaction`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately in the program of the user i can not rollback a transaction.

Comment: Then you probably need to do the magic with `autonomous transaction`.